# Algorithm for remainder operation in verilog that executes in a single clock cycle

Tags: algorithm, numbers, verilog, modulo, xilinx

Any links to literature discussing the algorithm would suffice.
I am working on a verilog code in xilinx. It uses verilog's inbuilt % operator. The problem is that % cannot be synthesized in xilinx.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a specific divisor in mind, or is it a general modulo operation?  For a general modulo solution, you basically need a full blown divider, AFAIK.

Comment: This is fixed-point division? Dividing by 2 with fixed-point is pretty easy.

Answer (score 2):

In most tools, % can be simulated but not synthesized.

For example, if you need m % n, if n is a fixed number, especially it is 2's power, you can write one easily.

If n is not 2's power, but the value range of m is small enough, you can build a table and do parallel comparisons to do the modulation.

Normally if m is random or n is not fixed, it is pretty difficult to do in hardware.
Probably it is better to change your hardware algorithm to avoid this modulation if possible.

Most of the time, you don't need an accurate modulation, reducing the precision of m and n would help.

Comment: I am trying to synthesize code for Diffie-Hellman key exchange. In my case m is 1024 bits. So, its not power of 2, its big and accurate modulation is required!

Comment: I don't know Diffie-Hellman exactly but googled it. It seems a (g**b)%p calculation is needed, while g, b and p are small number. If I am right, (g**b)%p == ((g%p)**b)%p. For example, (28**16)%53 == (((28**4)%53)**4)%53, and in this calculation, every number is generally small enough to handle. On the other hand, any chance to do pipelined calculation? It seems possible for me.